# Why does this python implementation of the Scheirer-Ray-Hare test give me different results than the same test from rcompanion?

Tags: python, r, debugging, math

I ran [this Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/jpinzonc/Scheirer-Ray-Hare-Test/blob/master/Scheirer-Ray-Hare%20Test.ipynb) with a Python implementation of the Scheirer-Ray-Hare test on [my own data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rt_Q4J069M1molc3Ze9CJyz8-imULvfw/view?usp=sharing) (which has two independent variables with two levels and one dependent measure), formatted to be like the example data in the repo. I ran the same test using the rcompanion package [(see a Colab notebook here)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N-cQKLZ9iR_bP_dChkutWBms9fwouhs_?usp=sharing) and got different results. I went through the Python implementation closely (running/printing each line to check the results) and am not able to spot why the results would be different.

From what I can see, the difference in results occurs at the calculation of the sum of squares; the rcompanion sum of squares is unequal to the sum of squares calculated in the Python inplementation (cell 8). I would appreciate help finding where the specific issue is in the Python implementation, or if the difference is due to some parameter in the rcompanion function that I did not understand (I did play around with these parameters and did not see the two results converge).

Thanks!

Comment: I assume line 14 of your data has an error, in that `Crop` should have a value of 1.  This could be a source of a discrepancy, as this results in an unbalanced design, and different methods for calculating sums of squares could give different results.  The `rcompanion` function has options for type I and type II sums of squares, which will give different results for your data. ... Can you post a small reproducible example in both R and Python with results ?